# How do I solve Quaternion Equations?

Tags: quaternions

I'm trying to calculate the sum of these 2 equations but I'm really having trouble. Here are the 2 quaternions that I'm trying to find the sum of:

$q_1 = 2 − i + j + 3k$, and

$q_2 = −1 + i + 4j − 2k$.

I'm aware that to get the sum of two quaternions you do something like this:

$a+b=(a_1+b_1)+(a_2+b_2)i+(a_3+b_3)j+(a_4+b_4)k$

This sort of formula makes sense but I can't figure out how I get the values of $i$, $j$ and $k$ on the right hand side. Could someone either care to explain the process of getting the sum of these equations or maybe provide a link that could help refresh my memory on this?

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble understanding? If you have complex numbers $c_1=2-3i$ and $c_2=-1+i$, you just add the individual parts together as $c_1+c_2=(2-1)+(-3+1)i=1-2i$. Can you go from here to the quaternions?

Comment: I'll just mention that it sounds strange to say you're solving equations; it seems more natural to say that you're doing arithmetic with quaternions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps writing like this will help you understand what's happening

\begin{align}
q_1 &=&  2&& - 1&\color{red}{i}& + 1&\color{blue}{j}& + 3&\color{orange}{k}& \\
q_2 &=& -1&& + 1&\color{red}{i}& + 4&\color{blue}{j}& - 2&\color{orange}{k}& \\
q_1 + q_2 &=& (2 - 1)&& + (-1 + 1)&\color{red}{i}& + (1 + 4)&\color{blue}{j}& + (3-2)&\color{orange}{k}
\end{align}

So that

$$
q_1 + q_2 = 1 + 5\color{blue}{j} + \color{orange}{k}
$$

Comment: This makes perfect sense but can I just ask, if I was writing this in a program what value am I assigning to "k" for example?

Comment: @OpenSource Just $1$: $1\color{orange}{k}$

Comment: It's all coming back to me now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
q_1 + q_2 & = (2−i+j+3k) + (−1+i+4j−2k) & \\
& = (2 + -1) + (-i + i) + (j + 4j) + (3k - 2k) & \text{(group like terms)} \\
& = (2 + -1) + (-1 + 1)i + (1 + 4)j + (3 - 2)k & \text{(factor)} \\
& = 1 + 5j + 1k & \text{(simplify)} 
\end{align*}$$